# Compressing files using p7zip from the command-line

Tags: command-line, compression, 7z

I would like to compress four ISO files using 7z into a new archive called `ISOs.7z` from the command-line on my Sabayon machine. These are the commands I have tried so far (I know none of these specify the output 7z archive's name, just starting simple with these commands so that I can get the ropes of compressing with 7z):

```
7z a chakra-2015.11-fermi-x86_64.iso openSUSE-Leap-42.1-DVD-x86_64.iso PCBSD10.2-RELEASE-08-19-2015-x64-DVD-USB.iso Sabayon_Linux_15.11_amd64_MATE.iso
```

and

```
7za a chakra-2015.11-fermi-x86_64.iso openSUSE-Leap-42.1-DVD-x86_64.iso PCBSD10.2-RELEASE-08-19-2015-x64-DVD-USB.iso Sabayon_Linux_15.11_amd64_MATE.iso
```

neither worked. The latter of these gave:

```
Open archive: chakra-2015.11-fermi-x86_64.iso

ERRORS:
There are data after the end of archive

--
Path = chakra-2015.11-fermi-x86_64.iso
Type = xz
ERRORS:
There are data after the end of archive
Offset = 205312
Physical Size = 10840636
Tail Size = 2144760772
Method = LZMA2:23
Streams = 1
Blocks = 1


Error:
There is some data block after the end of the archive
E_NOTIMPL


System ERROR:
E_NOTIMPL
```

Comment: You did not specify the archive name: `7z a <archive.7z> <file1> <file2> …`

Comment: the correct syntax is **7z a isos.7z   *.iso**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
7z a isos.7z *.iso
```

or

```
7z a isos.7z chakra-2015.11-fermi-x86_64.iso openSUSE-Leap-42.1-DVD-x86_64.iso PCBSD10.2-RELEASE-08-19-2015-x64-DVD-USB.iso Sabayon_Linux_15.11_amd64_MATE.iso
```